# replace is undefined in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I tried to do this line of code but it says

```
<a href="/<%= user.name.replace(/ /g, '-') %>">go to page</a>
```

> replace is undefined method

Comment: If I remember correctly, when you use `<%=`, you are dumping data, you should try to do the replace server side and send it inside the `render`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<a href="/<%= String(user.name).replace(/ /g, '-') %>">go to page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you able to try assigning like this

`var username = user.name;
username.replace(/ /g, '-');`

Answer (score 0):

On node side,

```
var username = user.name.replace(/ /g, '-');

res.render('your_html_file_path',{username : username };
```

In VIEW :

`<a href="/<%= user.name.replace(/ /g, '-') %>">go to page</a>`

Comment: What if i have 20 over username in one mongoose operations. doing this will spawn a problem?

Comment: Then you have to loop it in your server script